# Imposible subir fotos al Storage de tiempo real de Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

saludos a los **Experto y grandes conocedores de la programacion**, les tengo el siguiente problema:

EN mi activity Tengo **2 ImageView y un boton**.

Si le das click a cualquiera de las imageview, ya sea la **Imagen A** o la **ImagenB**, me abre la galeria del telefono y puedo escoger una imagen, y se me muestra en el ImageView que seleccione, hasta alli todo perfecto

Luego tengo un **boton SUBIRFOTOS**, que al darle click cree una funcion para que ambas imagenes ya escogidas y mostradas en los respectivos ImageView sean subidas al **Storage de firebase**.

La funcion va perfecto, pero tan solo me sube una de las fotos, no me sube ambas fotos, y de verdad que ni idea de lo que estoy realizando mal, me gustaria que chequearan el codigo a ver que le falto a la funcion del boton, para que me suba ambas fotos y no solo una de las fotos.

**De antemano Gracias a todos toda la ayuda.**

-------------- **Layout** -------------

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                            android:id="@+id/imagenA"
                                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                                            android:src="@drawable/subirfoto"
                                            app:civ_border_width="3dp"
                                            app:civ_border_color="@color/banner" />


                                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                            android:id="@+id/imagenB"
                                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                                            android:src="@drawable/subirfoto"
                                            app:civ_border_width="3dp"
                                            app:civ_border_color="@color/banner" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/subirfotos"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="60dp" />

                                </LinearLayout>
```

--------------**Java** ----------------

```
public class crearcampeonato extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button subirfotos;
    private CircleImageView imagenA, imagenB, currentImageView;
    private static final int ImageBack = 1;
    private StorageReference carpeta;
    Uri ImageResultadoUri, ImageUri;
    private StorageReference carpeta;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crearcampeonato);

       carpeta = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("fotos");
       imagenA = findViewById(R.id.imagenA);
       imagenB = findViewById(R.id.imagenB);
      subirfotos = findViewById(R.id.btnsubirfotos);

        imagenA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentImageView = imagenA;
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, ImageBack);
            }
        });

        imagenB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentImageView = imagenB;
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, ImageBack);
            }
        });

           // Boton subir Fotos

          subirfotos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                subiendostorage();

            }
        });

    }

      //Comienzo Funcion Boton Subir Fotos

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private void subiendostorage() {

        if (ImageUri!=null)
        {
            StorageReference FilePath = carpeta.child(Objects.requireNonNull(ImageResultadoUri.getLastPathSegment()));
            FilePath.putFile(ImageResultadoUri).addOnCompleteListener(new
        OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

        if (task.isSuccessful())
         {
        Toast.makeText(crearcampeonato.this, "Foto Cargada Correctamente",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
          else
          {
          String mensaje = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).toString();
          Toast.makeText(crearcampeonato.this, "Error:" + mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

          }
         });
        }

    }

    // Final Funcion Subir Fotos

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ImageBack && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null)
        {
            ImageUri = data.getData();
            CropImage.activity(ImageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                    .start(this);
        }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode ==
                RESULT_OK) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            assert result != null;
            ImageResultadoUri = result.getUri();
        }

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),
                    ImageResultadoUri);
            Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200,200,true);
            currentImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Revisaste el LogCat ? de otra forma pueden ser varias las causas...

Answer (score 0):

Sólo te sube una de las fotos porque nunca estás cacheando las dos uris (sólo una de ellas, la de la última imagen añadida) y tampoco las estás enviando, sólo una de ellas:

```
if (ImageUri!=null)
```

¿Qué es ImageUri? ¿La Uri del imageView A o B? 
En segundo lugar da igual si es null o no, porque lo que realmente te interesa saber es si ImageResultadoUri no es null...

Para poder guardar las imágenes, una solución rápida es:

1. Crear una variable en el scope de la clase que sea un `HashMap<Int, Uri>`, donde Int es la id de la vista (imageView A o B) y la Uri que recuperas de la galería.  De esta manera si antes de guardar quieres cargar una nueva imagen, al tener el mismo identificador en el HashMap, sobreescribirá el anterior.  Ej: `HashMap<Integer, Uri> urisMap = new HashMap<>(); // En el scope`
2. En el onActivityResult guarda tu Uri: 
   `urisMap.put(currentImageView, yourUri);`
3. En el método `subiendostorage()`, si Firebase te permite enviar las dos imágenes juntas, perfecto... si no te lo permite, recorre el HashMap (con Java 1.8 tienes el forEach con lambda) y ve guardando una a una.

Con ésto debería funcionarte siempre y cuando el hilo principal no quede bloqueado... hacer una llamada es un proceso costoso para el sistema, por lo que las acciones más pesadas deberían realizarse en otro hilo.  Investiga los Threads, Handler y callbacks y, después de esto, mira las corrutinas y ya tendrás una buena base para afrontar estos problemas.

Por último deberías revisar todo el approach en general con lo que quieres hacer, si realmente necesitas dos imageview que hacen lo mismo en la UI, igual con uno es suficiente y simplemente con mostrar una lista con las imágenes antes de subirlas y un botón de borrar si se quieren eliminar ya lo tendrías resuelto...

Comment: Hola Manuel, gracias por orientarme, trabajare en lo que comentas y te escribire cualquier cosa, Gracias por la ayuda siempre

Comment: Perfecto, y recuerda valorar la respuesta si te ha ayudado.

Comment: Te cuento Manuel yo antes tenia el codigo del boton Subiendostorage directamente en el onActivityResult y alli todo perfecto, al escoger la imagen A automaticamente me subia la imagen al storage e igual con la B, lo que no podia mostrar era cada imagen en su respectivo ImageView, que fue lo primero que me ayudastes. Pero se complico al querer implementar el metodo de subir la imagen a un boton adicional, ya que ese boton va a reliazar varias funciones y necesitaba que todo se realizara al darle click al boton. Pero es como complicado para mi, estoy tratando con lo que enviastes, ya te contare